# "A house with an odd number of outside doors cannot have rooms with only 0 or 2 doors"

Tags: graph-theory, puzzle

This problem came up on my proofs class, but there appears to be some extra condition that isn't specified, because I came up with a counter example. Note that it has 3 outside doors and the middle room has 2 doors. [image: Figure 1]

My professor couldn't help, since this question was written by another prof when he was teaching the class. I understand the handshaking lemma, which I think might be relevant but I don't really see how.
Can someone tell me what element of graph theory this problem is getting at and why my counterexample is wrong?

Comment: Perhaps the intended reading of the statement is that **Given that every room has exactly two or zero doors** such a house cannot have an odd number of outside doors.  Your example would not then work since you have a room with four doors and a room with only one door.

Comment: I suspect you are misquoting, or misreading, the problem.  It's just a guess, but maybe it asked "given a house with an odd number of external doors, show that at least one room has a number of doors which is neither $0$ nor $2$."

Comment: As an aside, both lulu's and my interpretations are the same and our restatements of the problem are equivalent, just one is phrased in the contrapositive.

Comment: I thought so too, but why wouldn't the condition be "not every room has an _even_ number of doors?" If the problem is trying to get at the handshaking lemma, then that wording would be much more general, rather than having us fixate on the specifc values of 0 or 2

Comment: Just because one of the conditions could be relaxed to something more general doesn't mean that the original phrasing of the question is untrue.  You can prove a harder statement if you like in order to use that result to prove an easier statement, it happens all the time.  Could you weaken the condition?  Sure.  Is there a specific reason why the author didn't weaken the condition from the start?  You'd have to ask him/her.  Perhaps he/she had a simpler proof in mind that works only for the more specific case.

Comment: I think the intent of the problem is that it is not possible to have both an odd number of outside doors and every room in the house a 0-or-2-door room.

Comment: If a room has zero doors, is it really a room? :P But seriously, a room with zero doors can be safely ignored. It doesn't contribute anything to the rest of the house or the number of external doors. In the graph theory interpretation of this problem, a room with zero doors would just be an isolated node.

Answer (score 1):

I think the phrasing of the title is bad. The generalization of the the question is: a house with an odd number of exterior doors must have at least one room with an odd number of doors. In other words, it's not possible to have a house where each room has an even number of doors.

To see this, the outside of the house can be unified into one vertex, and all rooms get their own vertex. Each door is represented by an edge. Now sum over the degree of each vertex. The outside vertex has odd degree $d_o$, whereas each room has degree $d_r$. So $d_o+\sum_{r=1}^Nd_r=2E$.

Then $2E-d_o$ is odd. This implies you must have at least one room with an odd number of doors.

So your counterexample doesn't work as you have a room with 1 door.